# Facebook: Get access token to post as a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Is it possible to somehow get an access token to use the facebook api like a user that clicked "use facebook as "?

What I'm trying to do is to allow my website to post messages to the facebook page's wall. I already have an app which I use to allow my users to login with their FB account. However, I'd prefer not to require a page admin to authorize full manage_pages to my app. I already added the app to my FB page, but there are no options to give that app some permissions for my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

In the official documentation page about [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) it's written:

> **Page access_token**
>
> An access_token used to manage a page. This is used
> when you want to perform an operation acting as a Page. This access
> token is retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts or to
> /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages permission. Getting
> /USER_ID/accounts will return a list of Pages (including app profile
> pages) to which the user has administrative access in addition to an
> access_token for each Page. Alternatively, you can get a page access
> token for a single, specific, page by issuing an HTTP GET to
> /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages permission (you
> must ask for the access_token field specifically via the fields=
> parameter). See the documentation for the Page object for more
> information. NOTE: After November 1, 2011, manage_pages permission
> will be required for all access to a user's pages via this connection,
> i.e. for both reading the user's pages and also retrieving
> access_tokens for those pages. See the documentation for the User
> object for more information.

Comment: So I cannot use an app only for a single page without giving it access to ALL pages I own/administrate?!